# xslt transform list and take max

Tags: dictionary, transform, xslt-1.0

I want to:

1. select all attributes "foo", which are string values, and store the values in a list.
2. transform each value of attribute "foo" in this list using some map in my xslt to a number.
3. select the max value of the list and output that.

So given the following xml:

```
<t>
    <tag foo="A">apples</tag>
    <tag foo="C">oranges</tag>
    <tag foo="B">trees</tag>
</t>
```

And the following mapping:

```
<xsl:variable name="myMap">
    <entry key="A">1</entry>
    <entry key="B">2</entry>
    <entry key="C">3</entry>
</xsl:variable>
```

The output would be:

```
<max>3</max>
```

Another question, why can't I indent my code? I'm putting spaces but it's not working.

Comment: The `max()` function isn't available in XSLT 1.0. Can you use an XSLT 2.0 solution? If so, why this question is tagged as "xslt-1.0"?

Comment: I saw the max function but haven't used it yet because I haven't managed to get past step 2. So if I can't use the max function in XSLT 1.0 this is going to be hard : /

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I This standard XSLT 1.0 transformation** (most resembling your approach):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vrtfMap">
  <entry key="A" value="1"/>
  <entry key="B" value="2"/>
  <entry key="C" value="3"/>
  <entry key="X" value="8"/>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vMap" select=
  "document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name = 'vrtfMap']/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@foo">
  <xsl:attribute name="foo">
   <xsl:value-of select="$vMap[@key = current()]/@value"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (as you didn't provide any):

```
<t foo="X">
    <a foo="A">
        <b foo="B"/>
    </a>
    <c foo="C"/>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<t foo="8">
   <a foo="1">
      <b foo="2"/>
   </a>
   <c foo="3"/>
</t>
```

**Explanation**: Appropriate use of the XSLT **[`current()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-current)** function.

---

**II. XSLT 1.0 solution using keys for speed**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kValFromKey" match="entry/@value" use="../@key"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vrtfMap">
  <entry key="A" value="1"/>
  <entry key="B" value="2"/>
  <entry key="C" value="3"/>
  <entry key="X" value="8"/>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vMap" select=
  "document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name = 'vrtfMap']/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@foo">
  <xsl:variable name="vCur" select="."/>

  <xsl:attribute name="foo">
   <xsl:for-each select="document('')">
    <xsl:value-of select="key('kValFromKey', $vCur)"/>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced**.

**Explanation**:

1. Use of `<xsl:for-each select="document('')">` to set the current document to the stylesheet, so that the `key()` function will use the key index built for this document.
2. Saving the node matched by the template in a variable so that we can use it inside the `xsl:for-each` -- `current()` cannot be correctly used here, because it gets the current node on which `xsl:for-each` operates.

**UPDATE**: The OP has now clarified in a comment that his biggest problem is finding the maximum.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:variable name="vrtfMap">
      <entry key="A" value="1"/>
      <entry key="B" value="2"/>
      <entry key="C" value="3"/>
     </xsl:variable>

     <xsl:variable name="vMap" select=
      "document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name = 'vrtfMap']/*"/>

     <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="."/>

      <xsl:variable name="vFoosMapped"
           select="$vMap[@key = $vDoc/*/*/@foo]"/>
      <max>
       <xsl:value-of select=
         "$vFoosMapped
            [not($vFoosMapped/@value > @value)]
              /@value
         "/>
      </max>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When given this XML document** (the one provided by the OP lacks a singlr top element):

```
<t>
    <tag foo="A">apples</tag>
    <tag foo="C">oranges</tag>
    <tag foo="B">trees</tag>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<max>3</max>
```

**Remark**: A more efficient way of calculating maximum (or minimum -- in a similar way) in XSLT 1.0 is to do this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:variable name="vrtfMap">
      <entry key="A" value="1"/>
      <entry key="B" value="2"/>
      <entry key="C" value="3"/>
     </xsl:variable>

     <xsl:variable name="vMap" select=
      "document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name = 'vrtfMap']/*"/>

     <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="."/>

      <xsl:variable name="vFoosMapped"
           select="$vMap[@key = $vDoc/*/*/@foo]"/>
      <max>
       <xsl:for-each select="$vFoosMapped">
         <xsl:sort select="@value" data-type="number" order="descending"/>

         <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
          <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
         </xsl:if>
       </xsl:for-each>
      </max>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

> Another question, why can't I indent my code? I'm putting spaces but
>   it's not working.

This is a SO bug that they failed to fix for many months.

**Most probably you are using IE. If your version is 9, then do the following**:

1. Press F12.
2. In the window that pops up click on the right-most menu and select: "Document mode: IE9 Standards"

Now you should be able to see the code with indentation.

Comment: I apologize Dimitre. I failed to be explicit enough when stating (1). I don't want to search and replace what's in the xml. I want to find the max value in the xml based on some mapping and output only that one value. I really should have given an example. I've corrected my question to give the example.

Comment: @Thirlan: Yes, I commented on a contradiction in your question -- you said that you easily did that.

Comment: @Thirlan: There is still a contradiction: You say: "*1 and 2 are easy. I can do the select and use the max function. 2 is the real problem and seems to be mind blowingly hard*". I thought that you wanted to sa: **3** is the real problem.  Please, correct.

Comment: Sorry, I've stripped my opinions and garbage from the question. I hope the question with the examples are clear. Also if this is only feasible in xslt 2.0 then I'd be grateful for the solution in 2.0 and I'll just have to figure out how to get 2.0 working on my box.

Comment: @Thirlan: I have updated my answer (look near the end) and provided a solution to your real problem. As for XSLT 2.0 -- install and use it, despite the fact that I gave you an XSLT 1.0 solution -- you'd thank me for this advice :)

Comment: @Thirlan: I also provided a second, more efficient solution of finding maximums or minimums, though this no longer is a single XPath expression.

Comment: I have some questions. Why must we reselect the vrtfMap into the vMap? And for vFoosMapped, why can't we use //@foo instead of $vDoc/*/*/@foo ?

Comment: @Thirlan: You need to read About the XSLT 1.0 so called RTF (Result Tree Fragment) type. `$vrtfMap` is of type RTF and its members can't be accessed unless it is converted to a "normal tree". The trick with the `document()` function (and it works only if the contents of the rtf variable is static) is to avoid this limitation. As for using `//foo` -- yes, it can be used, but one needs to avoid using the `//` pseudo-operator as in many cases it is very inefficient (causes the whole tree to be traversed).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8589/discussion-between-thirlan-and-dimitre-novatchev)